# reset button after loader shows

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys I am trying to create a button that turns into a loader when submitted and then returns to a button after form submits successfully.

I think my problem comes within the JS. 
Not sure in how to add a timeout to my JS to make the loader hidden after a certain time or after the PHP has submitted.
My form runs through phpmailer and through ajax gives an alert mgs that shows it has been send, tho usually the mgs takes awhile to show, causing clients to resubmit

```js
function ButtonClicked() {
  document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
  document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = ""; // to display
  return true;
}
var FirstLoading = true;

function RestoreSubmitButton() {
  if (FirstLoading) {
    FirstLoading = false;
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = ""; // to display
  document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}
// To disable restoring submit button, disable or delete next line.
document.onfocus = RestoreSubmitButton;
```

```css
.cssload-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.cssload-whirlpool,
.cssload-whirlpool::before,
.cssload-whirlpool::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #08d108;
  border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 924px;
  -o-border-radius: 924px;
  -ms-border-radius: 924px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 924px;
  -moz-border-radius: 924px;
}

.cssload-whirlpool {
  margin: -23px 0 0 -23px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
}

.cssload-whirlpool::before {
  content: "";
  margin: -21px 0 0 -21px;
  height: 41px;
  width: 41px;
  animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 1450ms linear infinite;
}

.cssload-whirlpool::after {
  content: "";
  margin: -27px 0 0 -27px;
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  animation: cssload-rotate 2900ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cssload-rotate 2900ms linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 2900ms linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 2900ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 2900ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cssload-rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-rotate {
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-rotate {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <div id="formsubmitbutton">
    <button onclick="ButtonClicked()" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Send <i class="ion-android-arrow-forward"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div id="buttonreplacement" style="display:none;">
    <div class="cssload-container">
      <div class="cssload-whirlpool"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to show the 'send' button again and hide the loader after success message from your phpmailer?

Comment: yea basically if form is done, it should show the button again

Answer (score 0):

You Should call ButtonClicked and RestoreSubmitButton from the ajax request like this:

```
function sendFormData(){
    ButtonClicked(); //Start to display loading indicator before sending the request

   $.ajax({
         url:'ServiceToFetchDocType',
         type:'post',
         cache:false,
         success: function(response){
             /* Ajax has now completed so you can re-render the button now*/
             RestoreSubmitButton();
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the console or something? 
an you post your ajax request ?